# [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url] crashes in Simulator, but works on iPad?

Tags: ios5, uimanageddocument

I'm trying to set up a managedDocument in my app and use CoreData to update this document. I added this code to my app in viewDidLoad and my app now crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
 self.Database=[[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
```

I verified that url is a valid url. The crash only occurs on the simulator if I run it on the device I get beyond this point.

Does anyone know where to start to fix this?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Thanks for the link. I finally got it to work by deleting the app from the simulator and then running it.